regarding auto restart and freeze
While i connect the external monitor or keyboard some time ubuntu freeze or being restart automatically
device info
acer swift 14 go 16gb ddr5ram/512 gb gen 4 ssd
graphics is amd radeon and processor is amd ryzen 5 7h series

You can see the log entries just before the last crash with the terminal command sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e.
